# how to reminder daily,weekly or yearly calendar event in iphone?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I make a application how save or show new calendar events. through the help of [https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar.git,](https://github.com/stelford/Titanium-Calendar.git)

but, how i reminder daily, weekly or yearly, and how to alert through any alarm. if any idea than help me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's **iOS**. You can't set the native alarm from your app. For the reminder, maybe you can set a repeating calendar event? or look into [LocalNotification](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification-object).

Comment: but, when i delete this event from calendar then how i remove LocalNotification